# Are variables in python objects or is the value considered an object?

Tags: python

I was just wondering if variables or names were objects or if the value is the object, if you could explain it in-depth I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Ahh, beat me by 20 seconds :)

Comment: The name is just a label in the Python source code, that refers to an actual value.

Comment: What would the object be in this case?

Comment: In the context of "names and values in Python" then *value* is synonymous with *object*.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the **values** are objects, and the variables are just **labels** you use to refer to existing objects.

Any value in python is an object, has it's type and attributes. If you want to see it for your self, try to invoke the function `dir` passing a constant, like:

`dir(1)`

you will see all attributes associated with the int object `1`

Any variable in python can be assigned any object as it's value. You can look at the variable as something like a post it with a name inscribed in it. You can stick it to any object (your refrigerator, your TV, a chair), and it will still be the same label, but the object it's "naming" will be other. So, the variable is just a way to bind a name to an object.